# When does the disposer execute?

Tags: java, jboss, cdi, ejb-3.1, jboss-weld

I have a pojo producer which produces MyResourceManager.

> @TraderResouceManager @RequestScoped public MyResourceManager(){ ... ... }

MyResourceManger is injected into SLSB

> @inject @TraderDB private MyResourceManager rm;

The disposer is a follows

> public void close(@Disposes @TraderResouceManager MyResourceManager rm) {
>      rm.close();
>   }

**Question**

When does the close() execute ?

Is it before closing transaction or after closing the transaction ?

> EDIT : The question perhaps needs additional explanation. Lets take a database connection analogy.

I create a @producer with @RequestScoped, using a pojo which creates a new connection per request.

What I need is to dispose the connection at the end of request.
This connection is shared by other beans (for now SLSB). In a given request there may be many beans involved running inside a transaction.
Hence additionally I need to close the connection only after all the transactions are logically closed.

**Question**
Will I be able to achieve this behavior with above code when I use container managed transactions ?

Answer (score 0):

Close() executes when the current request is terminated since your producer method is request-scoped. If you call your SLSB from a JSF request or a servlet, then the lifeclye of those requests determines when MyResourceManager will be disposed. If your SLSB is remote, it will be terminated as soon as the call returns.